# Excel custom function not working in Online Excel

Tags: reactjs, excel, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I have created an excel custom function with a shared runtime environment. It's working fine in the desktop app, but when I run the same project on the server it's not working. My excel function is not working online. I don't know why its behavior change in an online environment.
Can anyone tell me why I am getting making mistakes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>a1753eec-7c8b-4dbd-ab74-3b30d63d9b15</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Contoso" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Write your own Excel functions in JavaScript." />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/lock.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/lock.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help" />
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:3000</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <Runtimes>
          <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long" />
        </Runtimes>
        <AllFormFactors>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
            <Script>
              <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url" />
            </Script>
            <Page>
              <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
            </Page>
            <Metadata>
              <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url" />
            </Metadata>
            <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace" />
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </AllFormFactors>
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title" />
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description" />
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" />
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Taskpane.Url" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <CustomTab id="TabAddIns">
              <Group id="CommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label" />
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control> 
              </Group>
              <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/lock.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/lock.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/lock.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Script.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.js" />
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Metadata.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.json" />
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Page.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.html" />
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Functions.Namespace" DefaultValue="contoso" />
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!" />
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Get help" />
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Login" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started." />
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: What is the specific error message you met? I found that there is something wrong with the `resid` of Namespace (i.e., "namespace") in line 44. Its `resid` should be the same as the id of `bt:String` in line 101, i.e., "Functions.Namespace". Try changing "namespace" to "Functions.Namespace" and see if this issue is solved.

Comment: When I execute this function it's showing #NAME  in the excel cell. I have tried Functions.Namespace instead of the namespace. But still not working.

Comment: A `#NAME` error generally means there has been an issue registering your functions. Sometimes when there has been another add-in with the same namespace existed, the current add-in's custom functions will have such an error. Try changing DefaultValue of `bt:string` in line 101("contoso") to a unique value and see if the behavior of this issue changes (Note: At this point you should call custom functions with the new namespace). If this method does not work, please share your project with me so that I can help analyze it, thanks!

Comment: I have changed the namespace but still, it's not working.

Comment: how can share the project?

Comment: You can upload your project to Github, and share it with me (e.g., share a link or add me as collaborators by insert my username "rundongmsft").